# Can I access a cookie set by another domain?

Tags: cookies

Let's say that I got a cookie in my browser set by a website(not mine).
I got it from browsing that website obviously.
Now, I was wondering if I could display that cookie's value in my website... I tried, but it doesnt work. Though, I can access and display cookies set by my website. Here is the code I used:

```
  echo $_COOKIE["cookieice"];
```

I got the cookie's name from an addon called "Cookie Editor"  which works on FireFox.

Comment: cookies cannot be shared across domains. If they could, a site at nastythieves.ru could easily access your bankofamerica.com account. This is not a PHP thing. This is security enforced at the browser level. Unless there's an exploit in play, the browser will NOT, under ANY circumstances, send a cookie cross-domain.

Comment: You can get the cookie info in Firefox because Firefox is actually holding the cookie.  In order to get that information server-side, however, the browser needs to _send_ that cookie to the server.  For obvious reasons, browsers don't send cookies from Server A to Server B.  They'll send the cookies back to Server A on subsequent requests, but _only_ to Server A.

Comment: Will I be able to display that information in client-side, like with javascript or something?

Comment: Nope, client-side cookie availability is restricted by domain to prevent exactly what you are trying to do